# SQL Server 2019 installation failure: The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to install SQL Server 2019 evaluation edition on my laptop running Windows 10. I have selected all the available features to install.

I tried to install three times, and am seeing the same error as below after which some features like SQL database engine, Replication, Polybase, Machine Learning Service for Python are failing.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Error Text:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Community Technology Preview 3.2 Setup
------------------------------

The following error has occurred:

The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation.
```

Feature-wise failures:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: 1) Are you running the installer as Administrator, and 2) does the installation work with just a minimal set of features? You can add more features later.

Comment: Is your disk space sufficient?

Comment: @harrymc yes, my disk space is more than 100GB free.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Thanks for reminding to run as administrator, am going to try both the methods that you suggested today.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Installed everything in 2 sets of features as administrator. It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @Adarsh can you be more specific on what you did? I'm having the same issue and can't seem to find a workaround, even after several repair or uninstall/reinstall attempts

Comment: @NunoBarreiro I just had run the exe as administrator, selected a few main features first, like database engine, analysis services in the top node and then installed the remaining ones. I don't know the reason, but, it worked for me. See what Andrew Morton suggested in the first comment.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. Even trying to install just the database engine fails with the same error.

Comment: @Adarsh, even when "run as administrator" the error persisted. However I was able to final install the MSSQL database engine by changing the installation directories to C:\MSSQL instead of the subdirectory inside the Program Files, so it really seems like an user permissions issue.

Comment: @NunoBarreiro that's nice you figured it out. I am sure the error wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing to just install SQL Server 2016 instead of 2019...
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2016

Answer (score -1):

I also have this problem and think it is FILESTREAM-related.  See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ae783d76-5211-43a2-ba57-c1cad400dbb0/error-enabling-filestream-on-sql-2019

I uninstalled the messed up SQL Server 2019 installation, disabled Device Guard, rebooted, and re-ran the installation with all options and it worked.

Comment: I'm getting the issue and Guarded Host is disabled...